# error : The field ID must be a number. in @Html.DropDownListFor method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My model:

```
public class ViewRequestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some")]
    [Display(Name = "some")]
    public int RequestType { get; set; }
}
```

my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "P")]
    public PartialViewResult ViewRequests(ViewRequestModel model)
    {
        string vn = "";
        switch (model.RequestType)
        {
            ...
        }

        return PartialView(vn);
    }
```

my view:

```
@{
    var reqTypes = new List<ListItem> { new ListItem { Text = "t1", Value = "1" }, 
       new ListItem { Text = "t2", Value = "2" },
       new ListItem { Text = "t3", Value = "3" } };
 }
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RequestType, new SelectList(reqTypes), new { id = "ddlType" })

 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RequestType)
```

when I try to post my form, jquery validation blocks it and show the error `The field RequestType must be a number`

where's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where's my mistake?

The fact that you are mixing some classic WebForms classes (`ListItem`) with ASP.NET MVC. The consequence of this is that your `<option>` elements of the dropdown do not have a value attribute. So nothing gets submitted to the form and the validation obviously fails.

Here's the correct way to populate the dropdown:

```
var reqTypes = new[]
{ 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "t1", Value = "1" }, 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "t2", Value = "2" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "t3", Value = "3" } 
};

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.RequestType, 
    reqTypes, 
    new { id = "ddlType" }
)
```

As you can see from this example I am using the `SelectListItem` class which is specific for ASP.NET MVC. This generates:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field some must be a number." data-val-required="some" id="ddlType" name="RequestType">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">t1</option>
    <option value="2">t2</option>
    <option value="3">t3</option>
</select>
```

wheres your code generates:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field some must be a number." data-val-required="some" id="ddlType" name="RequestType">
    <option>t1</option>
    <option>t2</option>
    <option>t3</option>
</select>
```

The difference is obvious.

Comment: Your Rep is truely yours...! thanx

Comment: +1 for making the things clear. May i know why `List<SelectListItem>` is not used in ur code and `var` is used instead.

Comment: @wwcdwdcw, because the 2 are equivalent and I prefer typing 3 characters instead of 20 :-)